# Why does this DeleteCases not work?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction, pattern-matching

I believe this is simple but I couldn't figure out why this doesn't work.
Everything looks good to me.

```
DeleteCases[{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, x, 1, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, x, 
   1, -1}}, _?(#[[1 ;; 6]] == {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}) &]
```

Comment: Because `Head[(_?(#[[1 ;; 6]] == {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}) &)]` is `Function` not `Pattern`. Use this instead: `x_ /; (x[[1 ;; 6]] == {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0})`

Comment: Or this, which may be what you had in mind: `_?(#[[1 ;; 6]] == {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} &)`

Comment: @flinty I checked the one below as to make it. Aren't they similar?
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/197423/using-deletecases-with-a-defined-function-with-two-arguments-as-a-pattern

Comment: @MichaelE2 exactly! it is a subtle one

Comment: I still wonder why they are different? How the parentheses affect the result?

Comment: Ah, reading flinty again I think I get it.

Comment: The precedence of `?` and `&`. The code in the question is equivalent to `( _?(#[[1 ;; 6]] == {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}) ) &`. In general `_? body &` is equivalent to `(_? body) &`.  You need `_?(body &)`.

Comment: When you're not sure about the precedence, just click n times on the code, and the code piece will be selected outwards according to the precedence.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I guess so. It's more abstract though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it's a matter of precedence. When you're not sure about the precedence, just click n times on the code, and the code piece will be selected outwards according to the precedence:

[image]

As shown in the GIF above, after clicking on `&` 3 times, `_?(#[[1 ;; 6]] == {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}) &` is selected i.e. the whole `_?(#[[1 ;; 6]] == {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0})` has been included in the `Function`, which is undesired.

Alternatively, you can check the `FullForm`. It's not that handy, but still a good choice if you're not yet familiar with the real meaning of `_`, `?`, `&`, etc.

```
_?(#[[1 ;; 6]] == {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} &) // FullForm
(*
PatternTest[Blank[],Function[Equal[Part[Slot[1],Span[1,6]],List[0,0,0,0,0,0]]]]
 *)

_?(#[[1 ;; 6]] == {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}) & // FullForm
(*
Function[PatternTest[Blank[],Equal[Part[Slot[1],Span[1,6]],List[0,0,0,0,0,0]]]]
 *)
```

Comment: And for the more keyboard oriented folks, you can also use Ctrl+. in place of clicks for "precedence highlighting".